# Stop Implicit Typecast

Tags: c#, casting

My issue is within AMO in a C# console application.  I have a DataSourceView that has a table which has a column of type Decimal.

When I try to create a measure out of it, AMO says that it cannot create a measure because the data type is string.

I believe there may be some implicit typecasting going on in the background that is causing this.

Is there an application wide setting to stop implict typecasting?

Comment: Could you please provide some code? C# is normally strong-typed.

Comment: Please post the relevant lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to parse the string for the decimal -- decimal.Parse(s);

Of course you would want to make sure you handle the case where the string is not a decimal number.

Alternatively, you could use System.Convert

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the implementation of `DataSourceView` being used.

`DataSourceView` takes a data source, but can do any sort of transformation on that data. The result of an `ExecuteSelect()` call is just an `Enumerable` -- there is no guarantee of what you get out in terms of type fidelity; it is entirely contingent upon the implementation.